# Customized sip server to be used with doubang's idoubs

Tags: ios, sip, voip

I wish to use a VOIP SIP service for video and audio calls. After researching this I found out that **doubang** is a flexible framework for voip client.

I want to build an app which requires to connect to a customized SIP server for the communication (registration will be the process where user will be provided with an unique identifier with which user can communicate with others through the sip server). My question is can doubang's idoubs voip client communicate with other users using my sip server or it will use its own resource for that.

I am in need of all features like voice call, video call, Instant Messaging, SMS.

Is there any other framework which satisfies my needs?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) a multi-platform opens-source SIP client that is available on iOS among others.

Answer (score 0):

Kamailio (http://www.kamailio.org/w/)... tried and tested ...